# kamailio start failed ERROR: PID file does not exist

Tags: mysql, installation, kamailio, server

I have installed kamailio with the mysql, presence, nat, auth modules. All of them works on another Server(Amazone Ec2). Now i'm trying it on an Notebook, and get some problems.

When i try to start kamailio with the kamctl command:

> sudo kamctl start
>
> INFO: Starting Kamailio :
>
> ERROR: PID file /var/run/kamailio.pid does not exist -- Kamailio start failed

I have already tried, to touch this file, change settings for the mysql db, and searched other solutions on the web. But nothing helped me.

Answer (score 4):

Look in syslog file for error messages printed by Kamailio, you should get hints about the reason why is not starting -- syslog can be /var/log/syslog (debian like distros) or /var/log/messages (centos like distros).

You can also try to start it printing log messages to the terminal, something like:

```
kamailio -M 8 -E -e -dd
```

Then error messages can be seen directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot this question totally... I have found the solution. There was a problem between the versions of the moduls and the version of kamailio.

Comment: In my case bind was failing ("127.0.0.1: Address already in use") but above error was displayed. A look at /var/log/messages helped at first sight.

Answer (score 1):

Try to **create** a kamailio **folder** in the /var/run/ directory.

```
mkdir /var/run/kamailio
```

***#*** Used kamailio **4.3.1** installed from source.
***#*** Used this command to start:
`/usr/local/sbin/kamctl start`

Comment: `ERROR: PID..` Could also mean that config file has some errors in it. Try to start with default config file.